# How does one "imitate into everything"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin, translation-explanation, passive-voice, song-lyrics

"Good King Wenceslas" is a classic Christmas song, but its melody was taken from an older song: "Tempus Adest Floridum", from the Finnish carol book *Piae Cantiones* ("Pious Songs").

[image]

The first few lines of that song go:

> Tempus adest floridum,
>   surgunt namque flores
>   Vernales in omnibus,
>   imitantur mores

The translation seems straightforward, for the most part:

> The flowering time is here,
>   and the flowers are sprouting
>   Springtime customs now
>   imitate into everything(??)

But I'm very confused by the last line. How do the customs "imitate into everything"? Or does the verb *imitor* mean something else when connected to *in*?

Comment: Notably, another manuscript (from the Carmina Burana) has *immutantur* instead.

Comment: The punctuation seems to show that 'in omnibus' goes with the 'surgunt' clause, not the 'imitantur' clause.

Comment: @cnread Perhaps, but then what does "imitantur mores" mean on its own? I took this from Wikipedia, and now see I didn't have the capitalization quite right—I'll edit that.

Comment: Presumably, flores vernales is still the subject and, if I had to guess, I'd say this is a way of saying that they do the same thing that they do every year – that is, they imitate their custom.

Answer (score 4):

First, note that *in omnibus* can't mean "into everything" but only "in everything, in all things".

I would take *Vernales* as beginning a new sentence that goes on to *mores*, with those two words together meaning "springtime customs". The reason I think *Vernales* does not actually go with *flores*, as it would seem to at first sight, is that Medieval Latin poetry shows little in the way of enjambment: each line tends to correspond to a clause or sentence. See for examples the poems of the Archpoet, like [this one](http://www.intratext.com/IXT/LAT0479/_P9.HTM) in the same meter. And this line-to-clause correspondence seems to hold in the rest of [this same poem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_King_Wenceslas).

So we have a sentence *Vernales in omnibus imitantur mores*. The comma after *omnibus* is difficult, and my best guess is that it's there to show a break in the melody rather than in the syntax. Without it the sentence means "They imitate springtime customs in all things". Admittedly this is still a bit mysterious -- who's "they"? The flowers? People generally? An alternative, as Joonas suggests, is to take *imitor* as a true passive, "Springtime customs are imitated in all things", but this would be decidedly un-Classical.

Comment: Good point about the lack of enjambment in Medieval Latin poetry. You've convinced me to give up on the hypothesis that _Vernales_ modifies _flores._ Another piece of evidence: the melody has a cadence on _flores_ that strongly suggests that the thought has completed.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with cnread that capitalization seems to follow the verses, not implying a *hidden* punctuation. I also think that **mores** is the object of **imitantur**, the subject being **flores**.

This, IMO, has two readings:

1. **Flores imitantur mores [suos]**, as cnread says, *they imitate their custom*.
2. **Flores imitantur mores [bonos]**, *they flourish, just as virtues do*. I admit that this may sound a little far-fetched, but I can't help making sense of it this way in the context of Ecclesiastical Latin. **Mores** also mean *[manners, morals, character; in a good or bad sense](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmos)* .

FWIW there is an instance of **mores** being the object of **imitari** in Cicero in this specific sense:

> **imitari, Castor, potius avi mores disciplinamque debebas quam optimo et clarissimo viro fugitivi ore male dicere** ([Cic. Deiot. 10.28](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0011%3Atext%3DDeiot.%3Achapter%3D10%3Asection%3D28)) / *You ought, O Castor, rather to imitate the manner and principles of your grandfather, than calumniate a most virtuous and most illustrious man with the language of a runaway slave* ([Yonge, 1891](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Cic.%20Deiot.%2010.28&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059))

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option worth considering:
Perhaps *imitare* is meant as a non-deponent verb, making *imitantur* passive.
Thus *imitantur mores* would be read as something like "the traditions are followed".

Then the stanza would consist of three independent statements separated by commas:

- *Tempus adest floridum*
- *surgunt namque flores vernales in omnibus*
- *imitantur mores*

I'm not sure how to read *in omnibus*, though.
Perhaps "everywhere"?
That would make a lot of sense in context, but I'm not familiar with such use.

Comment: Flowers rise in/from all things?

Comment: @Rafael That's a possibility, too. I doesn't seem to make much of a semantic difference here, but your idea sounds more grammatical to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an uneducated guess, based on an evening's googling.

### Iam mutantur

An earlier version of the poem appears in the *Carmina Burana,* [§105 in this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=FW49AAAAYAAJ&dq=%22tempus%20adest%20floridum%22&pg=PA183#v=onepage&q&f=false) but usually counted §142:

> Tempus adest floridum,
> Surgunt namque flores,
> Vernales mox in omnibus
> **Iam mutantur** mores.

You have to fudge *Vernales* to fit the melody, which seems strange, but [another source](https://books.google.com/books?id=YIUQAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22tempus%20adest%20floridum%22&pg=PA60#v=onepage&q=%22tempus%20adest%20floridum%22&f=false) supports this. It seems OK if you make *Ver-* an upbeat.

Translating both literally and metrically:

> Now has come the florid time,
> For flowers are arising;
> Soon the ways in everything
> **Will be changed** to Springtime.

The following four lines continue the idea of evidence that Winter is now in the process of changing to Spring:

> Hoc quod frigus læserat,
> Reparant calores,
> Cernimus hoc fieri
> Per multos colores.
>
> What is injured by the cold,
> Heats are now restoring;
> We can tell it's happening
> By the many colors.

### Immutantur

[The Biblioteca Augustana's version](https://www.hs-augsburg.de/%7Eharsch/Chronologia/Lspost13/CarminaBurana/bur_cam5.html#142) is probably more authoritative:

> Tempus adest floridum,    surgunt namque flores
> vernales; mox in omnibus    **immutantur** mores.
> hoc, quod frigus leserat,    reparant calores;
> cernimus hoc fieri    per multos colores.

The word **immutantur** agrees better than **iam mutantur** with the idea of "being changed into" and the transitive use of *muto.*

The punctuation indicates that the curator thought that *vernales* modified *flores.* Leo Tepper posted the same conclusion in [his blog](http://thelatinreadingblog.blogspot.com/2014/05/carmina-burana-142-love-in-springtime.html). But don't jump on that bandwagon just yet. There's more evidence below.

### Imitantur

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Carmina_Burana&oldid=864169096#Musical_settings) reports that a "sanitized version" of *Tempus Adest Floridum* was published in the *Piæ Cantiones.* No source is given for that characterization, but the next two verses of the *Carmina Burana* version are about *virgines cum clericis* finding love in the meadows—probably not very pious by the standards of the [Swedish Reformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reformation_in_Sweden). [The version](http://www.lillhannus.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/tempusadestfloridum.pdf) in the *Piæ Cantiones* still describes meadows, but now it's only about plant life.

So, *Tempus Adest Floridum* got an edit, which fixed both the meter and the naughtiness. (The meter is still flawed, since the unstressed syllable *Ver-* is now on a strong beat, but this minor flaw seems common in Medieval Latin poetry.) The idea still seems to be that we are now witnessing the *change* to Spring. *Per multos colores,* in line 8, was revised to *per multos labores,* reinforcing the idea that something is causing everything to change.

### Inmutantur

Now, consider the medieval script in which **immutantur** would have been written. The letters *-immu-* would likely be a series of vertical strokes. If written **inmutantur**, the editor of the *Piæ Cantiones* could easily have mistaken the eight consecutive [minims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minim_(palaeography)) as the start of **immitantur** and then "corrected" the double *m.* (Perhaps **iam mutantur** is another transcription error introduced due to the same ambiguity.)

So that's my hypothesis: **imitantur** is a transcription error. The actual verb is **inmutantur** or **immutantur**, its subject is **mores**, and its object, properly an adjective, is **vernales**.

Commentary on [p. 253 of this edition](http://ks4.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/f/f4/IMSLP260656-SIBLEY1802.25581.933e-39087013435203score.pdf), from 1910, reports another likely transcription error in the *Piæ Cantiones,* in the second verse.

I welcome debunking from others more knowledgeable (or less). Some bases for doubt: palæography, transitive *inmuto,* and the erudition of Jacobus Finno and the other editors of the *Piæ Cantiones,* who presumably knew what they were doing.

---

After some more googling I found the relevant passage at the bottom of [folio 58v](http://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/0008/bsb00085130/images/index.html?id=00085130&groesser=&fip=xsewqwqrseayawxdsydsdasw&no=2&seite=120) in the *Carmina Burana*:

[image: Carmina Burana 58v]

It clearly reads **iam mutantur**, so now I wonder where the Biblioteca Augustana got **immutantur**. If that's a period after **omnibus**, then **vernales** modifies **flores** as in Joonas's hypothesis, yielding this literal translation: "…for the Spring flowers are arising soon in everything; already the ways are being changed."

---

After still more googling, I didn't find *mutari* used in the transitive way required for this hypothesis, but I did discover the impersonal passive, explained in [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/8774/118). The impersonal passive makes sense of both the *mutantur* and *imitatur* versions, without needing *vernales* to (jarringly) modify *flores,* so I'm judging the transcription-error hypothesis an error.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a second uneducated guess, based on yet more googling.

**Imitantur** is being used impersonally, referring to things in general, with the object **mores vernales**.

**In omnibus** here means "in all respects".

---

### Impersonal passive

Quoting note 149 of [this guide](https://books.google.com/books?id=pxQ9AAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA50&ots=0vKLI7XO8V&pg=PA50#v=onepage&q=impersonal%20passive&f=false) to *De Bello Civili*:

> The impersonal passive is often, very effectively, used in Latin to give the impression of an aggregation of separate but similar actions or movements, and so to convey an impression of vagueness or immensity…

*Imitari* is deponent, so the meaning is active, but perhaps it can still be used impersonally, especially in a poetic context such as this one. I gather that the impersonal passive carries a meaning similar to English "There was (a lot of) _____ing"; e.g. *Pugnatum est,* "There was (a lot of) fighting."

A basis for doubt: I haven't found another instance of a plural impersonal passive.

### Imitari mores

**Imitari mores** + a modifier for *mores* appears to be a classical Latin idiom, meaning "take after" or "behave like". Most often the *mores* are those of parents, as in this passage from [a Bible commentary](https://books.google.com/books?id=JrIrAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA172&ots=9svxlyJVc-&dq=%22imitari%20mores%22&pg=PA172#v=onepage&q=%22imitari%20mores%22&f=false):

> Proprium liberorum est **imitari mores** & exempla **parentum**; hoc est à natura.

Lucretius uses it in this passage:

> Saepe itaque ex uno tondentes gramina campo
> lanigerae pecudes et equorum duellica proles
> buceriaeque greges eodem sub tegmine caeli
> ex unoque sitim sedantes flumine aquai
> dissimili vivont specie, retinentque parentum
> naturam et **mores** generatim quaeque **imitantur**.
>
> Often wool-bearing cattle, truculent offspring of horses, and hornéd herds eating up the grass from one field under the same sky, and slaking their thirst from the water of one river, live each in a visibly different way, and retain their parents' nature, and **follow the ways** of their kind. [That is, even though the material they're made from is the same food, they remain different kinds of animals.]

Even though *imitari* can mean "faking, putting on a sham display", the meaning in these passages is that of behaving outwardly according to innate disposition—which might require a little external prodding or support to develop.

---

So, lines 3 and 4 of the song point poetically to varied and ubiquitous new behavior, happening **in omnibus**, all following the ways of Spring.

---

### More research

I did some more googling, and turned up very little to suggest that a plural impersonal verb can mean "things in general" as proposed above. "[The Latin Impersonal Passive](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/4432142.pdf?casa_token=lUBWf0VaocsAAAAA:iyw2KJceiT2vva_gKePK8p1fgTqrchb5M8iNGZEwB_vYdhH1uyHZUqRSrGXUVQqnkrL_z849NXWZcceBxX65aPLicUfEEhrEmWaNjJHiDl9XnhfLuTY)" by Harm Pinkster, p. 173, cites a few instances of it from Classical Latin, all where the implicit subject is a vague sense of "people" or "everybody" (and the verb is active). For example, *invenient hominem,* "the man will be discovered", literally "[people] will find the man"; *plerumque frumento utuntur importato,* "[people] mostly use imported corn." More common is *dicunt* with no subject to mean "many people are saying…" Arthur Sloman's *A Grammar of Classical Latin,* [§325.2](https://books.google.com/books?id=vx3iDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA221&ots=bsa18ycS5h&pg=PA221#v=onepage&q&f=false) gives impersonal *ferunt* and *tradunt* also in this sense.

So…I'm not sure. On the one hand, impersonal **imitantur** (and **immutantur**) seems to be a logical as well as poetic use of the grammar, with a meaning perfectly suited to the rest of the verse. On the other hand, I found little commentary or precedent for it. I hope someone more knowledgeable can tell us if the trained Medieval Latin ear would search for another word here as an explicit subject or be satisfied with no subject.